# Mac Mini 2018 Boot Camp 3 displays

Tags: mac, bootcamp

I have a 2018 Mac Mini and 3 HP E233 monitors. When using macOS the monitors all work great. However, when I use Boot Camp I can get two monitors working occasionally (sometimes there’s lots of flickering) but it's a pain and I have to press ‘Extend Display’ many times before it works. I then can’t get the third display to extend.

How do I get 3 monitors working in Windows through Boot Camp?

Note they’re attached, HDMI-HDMI, 2xUSB-C (or Thunderbolt, I can’t remember)-DisplayPort.